# Glitch: part of entries is cut off on badges pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Part of the text and symbols are covered by the new column.

Example: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/badges/61/talkative

Comment: No repro for me with Firefox 3.6.12 on Windows 7.  Environment and/or screenshot?

Comment: Oh, do you mean that part of entries (in my case, the bronze badge icon and the number of bronze badges of Suresh) is cut off?  Then I see the behavior.  (But I would not call this a problem with “alignment.”)

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: yes. I don't know what to call it, feel free to edit, I am making it CW (virtually). :)

Comment: How about something along “Glitch: part of entries is cut off on badges pages”?  Alignment is fine, but the problem is that the content is cut off.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: done, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The badges page has been redesigned.  It should be fine in the latest version.